# extracting multiples values from status table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've got 3 tables, 2 of which contain data and one contains statuses for the other two.

table **A** contains data 
table **B** contains data 
table **S** contains Status values for A and B

Example of Status table entries:

[image: status Table]

I'm trying to build a query to extract all the statuses for a range of data entries from A and B.
Example of desired result:

[image: result Table]

I've already got a piece of code that works but is really slow, especially since there are like 10 statuses, and sometimes for hundreds of entries at a time.

```
select S.owner, S.foreign_key,
       s1 as ordered_Status, s2 as payed_Status, s3 as dispached_Status
from S as s1, S as s2, S as s3 
where s1 like '%ordered%'
and s2 like '%payed%'
and s3 like '%dispached%'
group by S.foreign_key;
```

The criteria by which i select the foreign_key is also not shown here but you can imagine it slows down the query even more.
There has to be a more efficient way of extracting this information.

I'm not sure it's relevant but as for the structures of table A and B:

Table A:
[image] 
Table B:
[image]

I make the selection based on product and time. The updated sql query based on the new information would be:

```
select S.owner, S.foreign_key,
       s1 as ordered_Status, s2 as payed_Status, s3 as dispached_Status
from S as s1, S as s2, S as s3, A, B
where s1 like '%ordered%'
and s1.foreign_key=A.id
and s2 like '%payed%'
and s2.foreign_key=A.id
and s3 like '%dispached%'
and s3.foreign_key=B.id
and B.fk_A=A.id
and B.fk_product=99
and A.date_created > '2017-07-04 08:00:00'
group by S.foreign_key;
```

Comment: Would you please share table structures ?

Answer (score 0):

The query is very slow due to the multiple self joins you do in your query. You can get your desired output by using the case when statement like below,

case(when(status_name='ordered' and status=1 then 1 else 0)) as ordered_status

Comment: Thanks, but this only allows me to edit the content of the result, it doesn't help with the search query.